# A-Frame mouse component doesn't release on mobile

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm using [A-Frame Mouse Cursor Component](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component) in my A-Frame project.

I've create an handler using the `registerComponent` method where when i click on a `a-entity` a modal (outer of canvas) is showing.

```
el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => { 
   //open modal 
});
```

when i click for the first time all going well but i've noticed that `a-grab-cursor a-grab-cursor-hover`classes keep on `cavas` tag.
So if i move the mobile device and i go across the `a-entity` it's seems that the camera click on it.

Only if a click outside all going back to the normality.

Any ideas?

Comment: No need for A-Frame mous component. anymorr. Use the built-in cursor component with mouse as rayOriging: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/cursor.html#properties_upevents

Answer (score 0):

To copy @DiegoMarcos comment to an actual SO answer:

No need for A-Frame mouse component anymore. Use the built-in cursor component with mouse as `rayOrigin: mouse`.

It is noted at the top of the README: https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component